# API for Enabling Mail Drop on iOS?

Tags: ios

Apparently iOS 9.0 now has iCloud Mail Drop support for emailing large attachments. However, I can't seem to find any APIs or techniques for enabling Mail Drop in my app. Has anyone found a way to do this?

Comment: cant find anything, seems not to be public. have you found anything?